# Jacoco 0.8.2 and Android Gradle plugin 3.2.0 test coverage

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, jacoco, test-coverage, android-gradle-3.0

I just tracked down an issue I'm having with partial coverage reports due to Android Gradle plugin 3.2.0

Jacoco is only generating coverage reports for less than 10% of my project.  If I revert back to 3.1.4, it behaves as expected.

Is there any known issue with AGP 3.2.+ and JaCoCo test coverage?

Answer (score 1):

In absence of [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates steps to reproduce your difficulty, one can only guess.

[Simple search in bugtracker of Android Gradle Plugin by word "JaCoCo"](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:192709%20jacoco) reveals for example

- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/112324134
- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/117956165
- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111569276
- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/120438249

with the same root cause

> **Location of class files has changed** in newer versions of AGP. You need
>   to change
>
> def debugTree = fileTree(dir:
>   "${buildDir}/intermediates/classes/debug", excludes: fileFilter)
>
> to
>
> def debugTree = fileTree(dir: "${buildDir}/intermediates/javac/debug",
>   excludes: fileFilter)

P.S. side-by-side comparison of old report with a new one can also give hints